# Is it possible to extend format of GCP HTTP(S) Load Balancing logging?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, gcp-load-balancer

We have logging enabled on our HTTP(S) Load Balancing for backend services, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring). It contains useful and structured data about [http requests](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#httprequest) made:

```
{
  "requestMethod": string,
  "requestUrl": string,
  "requestSize": string,
  "status": integer,
  "responseSize": string,
  "userAgent": string,
  "remoteIp": string,
  "serverIp": string,
  "referer": string,
  "latency": string,
  "cacheLookup": boolean,
  "cacheHit": boolean,
  "cacheValidatedWithOriginServer": boolean,
  "cacheFillBytes": string,
  "protocol": string
}
```

Is this possible to add some fields to that format? In particular, we're interested in logging some (but not all) HTTP headers passed in the request.